# Spring Data query with nullable Enum

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

We have a domain class

```
@Entity
public class Gallery implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Status status;

    // more attributes and getters/setters
}
```

The status is an enum:

```
public enum Status {

    OPEN (0, "offen"),
    ACTIVE (1, "aktiv"),
    INACTIVE (2, "inaktiv");

    // attributes, constructor...
}
```

Then we have a Spring Data repository with a query:

```
public interface GalleryRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Gallery, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT g FROM Gallery g WHERE (:status IS NULL or g.status = :status)")
    public List<Gallery> findBySearchCriteria(@Param("status") Status status);
}
```

The purpose of the `(:status IS NULL or g.status = :status)` is that we want all data, when no status is given and get only the appropriate data when status is given.

We get results from this query when status is null, but we don't get any result if status is e.g. ACTIVE, althought there is data in the database with status=ACTIVE.

Wenn we remove the `:status IS NULL or` from the query, we get results when status is ACTIVE. The query looks like

```
public interface GalleryRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Gallery, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT g FROM Gallery g WHERE (g.status = :status)")
    public List<Gallery> findBySearchCriteria(@Param("status") Status status);
}
```

I let log the SQL and parameters and when I run the SQL (with the `:status IS NULL or`) manually I get the expected results:

```
Hibernate: select gallery0_.id as id1_13_, gallery0_.institution_id as institut5_13_, gallery0_.internName as internNa2_13_, gallery0_.name as name3_13_, gallery0_.selectedShortId_id as selected6_13_, gallery0_.status as status4_13_ from Gallery gallery0_ where ? is null or gallery0_.status=?
2014-09-10 09:54:49,531 TRACE type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [1] as [VARBINARY] - ACTIVE
2014-09-10 09:54:49,531 TRACE type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [1] as [VARBINARY] - ACTIVE
2014-09-10 09:54:49,535 TRACE type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [2] as [VARBINARY] - ACTIVE
2014-09-10 09:54:49,535 TRACE type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [2] as [VARBINARY] - ACTIVE
```

The SQL is

```
select gallery0_.id as id1_13_, gallery0_.institution_id as institut5_13_, gallery0_.internName as internNa2_13_, gallery0_.name as name3_13_, gallery0_.selectedShortId_id as selected6_13_, gallery0_.status as status4_13_ 
from Gallery gallery0_ 
where 1 is null or gallery0_.status=1
```

When we use other data types (e.g. String) the construct (e.g. `(:name IS NULL or g.name = :name)` works like expected.

Is there anything wrong with this construct with enums or isn't it possible to do this in Spring Data/JPA?

A possible workaround we have is to write to queries, one with status and one without. Depending if the status is null or not we would call the appropriate method in the repository.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem with Enum parameters in spring data queries and managed to solve it by using Strings in the queries instead (keeping entity mappings as is with Enums):

```
public interface GalleryRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Gallery, Long> {

@Query("SELECT g FROM Gallery g WHERE (:status IS NULL or g.status = :status)")
    public List<Gallery> findBySearchCriteria(@Param("status") String status);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
public interface GalleryRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Gallery, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT g FROM Gallery g WHERE (CAST(:status AS string) IS NULL OR g.status = :status)")
    List<Gallery> findBySearchCriteria(@Param("status") Status status);
}
```

This method also works for dates.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply to create a query using method name?

```
public interface GalleryRepository extends JpaRepository<Gallery, Long> {
    public List<Gallery> findByStatus(Status status);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because when status is null this method finds all Galleries with status=null. But in this case we want all Galleries, no matter which status they have. Hint: In our system the query is more complex with more attributes which can be set or not. So a query seems to be the appropriate solution.